# XMLHttpRequest JS + Java

Tags: javascript, java

У меня есть некий сервер на Java, который должен при запросе отправить строку "Hello!"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {

                while (!input.ready()) ;

                String s;
                while ((s = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    if (s.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                out.write("Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                out.write("Content-Type: application/json\r\n");
                out.write("Content-Length: 17\r\n");
                out.write("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                out.write("Last-modified: Fri, 09 Aug 1996 14:21:40 GMT\r\n");
                out.write("\r\n");
                out.write("{\"name\": \"Hello\"}");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И есть клиент на JS, который должен получать ответ и выводить его

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.7:5000', true);
        xhr.send();
        
        xhr.onload = function () {
            alert(xhr.response);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        };
        
    </script>
```

Но в ответ ничего не приходит, а в Java выводится информация о запросе и все.
Что я сделал не так?

Comment: в браузере F12 вкладка Network и наблюдайте, что отправляется и что приходит.

Comment: @tym32167 выпадает только это (failed)net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: Какой http код ответа приходит?

Comment: в любом случае, у вас в сервере проблема, так как ответ от сервера приходит неверный. Вы, видимо, не возвращаете никакие заголовки и никакого кода ответа. Проглядите [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788242/312041).

Comment: Если сервер на Java и клиент на JavaScript на одном компе, тогда: `xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.7:5000', true);` заменить на `xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000', true);`

Comment: @not a Programmer,  вообще планируется, что клиент js будет на одном компе, а сервер на другом. Причем они будут соединены одной сетью (комп. кабинет)

Comment: Ну так когда они будут на разных компах тогда и будете указывать ip. А сейчас используйте localhost.

Comment: @tym32167 сделал код ответа как в приведенном примере, но приходит пустая строка. Нужен ли какой то определенный параметр для этого?

Comment: F12 нажимали? Смотрели, что за ответ приходит? Если у вас есть код, о котором вы задаете вопрос, то укажите этот ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: @tym32167 в консоли выпадает только это Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: то есть сайт вы открыли на `192.168.0.7:5000`, а запрос делаете на `localhost:5000`? Делайте запрос туда же, где открыт ваш сайт. Ваш запрос на сервер тупо заблокирован браузером, по умолчению, я так понял, вы не можете выполнять кроссдоменные запросы.

Comment: Вы не уточнили важный момент - что ваш HTML файл открыт просто как файл (по протоколу file://), что делает невозможным кросс доменные запросы. Подробней [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744697/312041)

Comment: Чтобы проверить как работает ваш сервер, вы можете выполнить обычный http запрос, например, открыть ваш сервер в браузере (`http://127.0.0.1:5000/`)

Comment: Все. Вопрос решен. Спасибо